# React : How to display a modal popup only for that specific div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

To make it more clear , basically what I'm trying to do is like Amazon

There will be a bunch of products and once you click on the product ,Only that product and its details will be displayed on the Popup Modal.

In my case , I have stored 3 data in an Array, I have mapped it out Which creates 3div and 3Modal Popup with buttons in each.

Once I click on the button of 1st div , I want the modal to be open for that first div only.

But right now when I click on the button all 3 Modal Popup.

I'm new to React , I can do this same thing in JQuery and Javascript, But I'm not able to achieve this in React.

Or is there a better approach to this ? Like rather than looping and creating 3modal popup Can we create just one modal popup, That will display the data of the particular div of which button is being clicked?

My Current Code:

App.js , Where i have created the Array

[image]

Product.Js Where its being mapped out into 3div and also has the modal popup

[image]

Let me know if you guys need more details

Thank you guys.

3 Div that is being dunamically created with the data from array
[image]

But when i Click on any button , popup for all div pops up , Thats the issue

Comment: What about global state? Do you use mobX or redux, or new react context API...?

Comment: For me it looks like modal should be separate component and spawning it depends on value showModal. You can laso do it without showModal: boolean - and simply call jQuery modal, but it's messy. Generally jQuery is not really reactive. You can use react-bootstrap package - it don't use jQuery and it's made reactively.

Comment: @Zydnar , I'm new to React so I haven't used redux .etc. Its just react thats all

Comment: Okay , But how will i popup for the particular div? Let me post the picture

Comment: Reactive means variable changes --> all depending views changes / actions are triggered. So you can use method inherited form React.Component - componentReceivedProps - and here if `showModal` would be prop you run your jQuery function. Or simply instead of using this prop from state, let jQuery handle some HTML. So create <div> inside Product component with modal content and run on `getModal` traditionally jQuery. so <div> need to have it's id so run it `$(id).modal('open');`

Comment: or do something like `showModal?$(id).modal('open'):$(id).modal('close');`

Comment: If you are still learning here is also free mobX tutorial: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-sync-the-ui-with-the-app-state-using-mobx-observable-and-observer-in-react and if you prefer easier unit testing and all in separate files (but more writing), here is redux tutorial: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-the-single-immutable-state-tree it may help you later...

Comment: Sir , I'm trying to achieve this in ReactJs , With Jquery i know how to do it , But same logic isnt working while doing in React way

Comment: Without jQuery you need separate component, and I told that as well.

Comment: Okay sir let me try it , But just to clarify once again, The solution you gave is for React right? Not JQuery , I'm a bit confused with the JQuery thing you keep saying. I'm looking for a solution in pure ReactJs. Is that the solution you gave?

Comment: Oh okay , Understood, I'll try it

Comment: Sorry, I tried to explain both ways so I complicated my response.

Comment: It isnt working sir

Comment: I think its really tough in react

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, all modal will pop up at the same time. All modal using exactly same state which is `this.state.showModal`. Once it gets `true` then all will just pop up. If you still like to have 3 modals like that. I suggest you to make the value of `showModal` state with JSON value. Maybe something like this:

```
state = {
    showModal: {}
}
```

then for `getModal()` function:

```
getModal = value => {//still using variable from `data.id`
    let key_to_update = {};
    key_to_update[value] = true;
    this.setState( {
        showModal: Object.assign( {}, this.state.showModal, key_to_update )
    } );
}
```

Then for the `<Modal/>` should looks like this:

```
<Modal show={this.state.showModal[data.id]} onClick={()=> this.hideModal(data.id)}/>
```

To hide the modal you can do opposite of `getModal()` as follow:

```
hideModal = value => {//still using variable from `data.id`
    let key_to_update = {};
    key_to_update[value] = false;//Just different on this
    this.setState( {
        showModal: Object.assign( {}, this.state.showModal, key_to_update )
    } );
}
```

If you still interested and have a problem to implement it, I can help you create a working demo. Because I am not really test the code, just make it based on my experience and quick analysis. However, personally, I like to have a single Modal for this kind of case. Just set a single "state" of "Product detail" then read that "state" from single Modal then show it at the same time.

**==== DEMO: MULTIPLE MODAL ELEMENT TECHNIQUE =====**

Just like your comment, because you only need to show single modal at a time, then it will be much easier. We don't need to have multiple true/false condition like above. We can just use `data.id` as the true/false check to the `showModal` state like follow:

```
class Product extends Component {
  state = {
    showModal: 0
  };

  getModal = value => {
    this.setState({ showModal: value });
  };

  hideModal = value => {
    this.setState({ showModal: 0 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.props.data.map((data, key) => (
          <div key={key} className="small">
            <p>Namsse: {data.name}</p>

            <button onClick={() => this.getModal(data.id)}>Popup</button>

            <Modal
              show={this.state.showModal === data.id}
              onHide={() => this.hideModal(data.id)}
              name={data.name}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Working Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/pkjvy72mw0

**===DEMO: SINGLE MODAL ELEMENT TECHNIQUE===**

You can also have only single `<Modal/>` element just like below:

```
class Product extends Component {
  state = {
    showModal: false,
    dataModal: {
      name: ""
    }
  };

  getModal = data => {
    this.setState({ showModal: true, dataModal: data });
  };

  hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.props.data.map((data, key) => (
          <div key={key} className="small">
            <p>Namsse: {data.name}</p>

            <button onClick={() => this.getModal(data)}>Popup</button>
          </div>
        ))}

        <Modal
          show={this.state.showModal}
          onHide={this.hideModal}
          name={this.state.dataModal.name}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/53x7m726xk

Comment: YUS EXACTLY, single modal is exactly what i wanted  , But its coming 3 because there is 3 div, So if there is 100 div then there will be 100 Modal, which is not the right way of doing it. So it would be really great if you could show me a working demo of single model for all the div. Thank you so much

Comment: Just make a demo which tried to use your existing code. Please check the update on my answer. Will try to make DEMO for single `<Modal/>` way.

Comment: Just add another demo with Single `<Modal/>` element method. Please let me know if you have any question regarding my code. Thanks.

Comment: You are AMAZING, Thank you so much for investing your time on me

Comment: Can use explain me this : this.setState({ showModal: true, dataModal: data }); The dataModal part , Is the "data" being stored in "name" which is inside dataModal?

Comment: No problem. I love coding anyway :). About `this.setState({ showModal: true, dataModal: data });` the `dataModal` part is just copy `data` record from loop of `this.props.data.map((data, key)`. So `dataModal` will have value something like : `{ id: 1, name: "Thanveer" }`, then you pass it as `props` to `<Modal/>` component and render it there.