# My modal is not working when I'm clicking on the image container in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanna dynamically render the images and then show the modal when the image is clicked and it should close when the modal background is clicked. Please help I'm new to React.

What should I do to make it work like is anything wrong in this. I'm stuck in this.

Whenever the images load from the api and I I click on them nothing happens.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Modal } from "./Modal";

class MediaGallery extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: "",
      show: false,
      loading: true
    };
  }

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  };
  hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const url =
      "https://amyapi.com";

    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          data: response.data,
          loading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    let content;

    if (this.state.loading) {
      content = (
        <div>
          <div className="modal is-active">
            <div className="modal-background has-background-primary" />
            <div className="modal-content has-text-centered">
              <p classname="image is-48x48">
                <img
                  src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sharadcodes/css_snippets/master/Infinity-1.4s-200px.gif?token=AIXQ22JWJBKUHGP45ANQZ4K5SW46A"
                  alt=""
                />
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      content = this.state.data.map((response, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={index}
            className="column is-one-quarter-desktop is-half-tablet"
            style={{ cursor: "zoom-in" }}
            onClick={this.showModal}
          >
            <Modal show={this.state.show} handleClose={this.hideModal}>
              <img src={response.acf.image} alt={response.acf.title} />
            </Modal>
            <div className="card cardimages">
              <div className="card-image" id="small-image-zoomable">
                <figure className="image is-3by2">
                  <img src={response.acf.image} alt={response.acf.title} />
                </figure>
                <div
                  className="card-content is-overlay is-clipped"
                  data={response.acf.title}
                >
                  <span className="tag is-primary">{response.acf.title}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <section className="hero is-medium is-bold has-background-black has-text-centered">
          <div className="hero-body">
            <div className="container">
              <h1 className="title is-1" style={{ color: "#FFD581" }}>
                Captured Moments
              </h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <div className="section" style={{ marginTop: "-1.2rem" }}>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="columns is-multiline" id="media-gallery">
              {content}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MediaGallery;
```

**And modal code is**

```
import React from "react";

export const Modal = ({ handleClose, show, children }) => {
  const showHideClassName = show ? "is-active" : "";

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={{ showHideClassName } + " modal"} id="modal">
        <div className="modal-background" onClick={handleClose} />
        <div className="modal-content" style={{ width: "70vw!important" }}>
          <p className="image ">{children}</p>
        </div>
        <button
          className="modal-close is-large"
          aria-label="close"
          onClick={handleClose}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: put model in ternary condition to show.

Comment: Means like where in the ternary condition?

Comment: Try this **className={`modal ${showHideClassName }`}** contains template literal.

Comment: It should be, `className={\`${showHideClassName} modal\`}` . Note the \`\` characters ie Template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle It's working but the model is not closing now. What to do ?

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle  And every image's model is opening behind one another

Comment: @SharadRaj: Ofc, as you send show prop to Modal, it'll open all the modals wherever it is called. You've to specifically send some unique key(maybe as an ID) in onClick function and as a prop in Modal to open that specific modal having this unique key. 

Please search more like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276832/react-how-to-display-a-modal-popup-only-for-that-specific-div

Also, please improve the naming conventions and follow the best practises.